# PECL_HTTP v2 setData()?

Tags: pecl

I am using pecl_http 2.5.3 now instead of the old version 1.7.6.

I changed my code to the new api, but i don't find a solution or opposite for setData from HttpResponse class from 1.7.6.

Can somebody help me?

want to change from pecl_http v1.7.6:

```
$response = new HttpResponse();
$response->status(201);
$response->setHeader('Location', 'blablub');
$response->setData(what ever);
$response->send(true);
```

to something like that with pecl_http v2.5.3:

```
$message = new http\Message;
$message->setType(http\Message::TYPE_RESPONSE);
$message->setResponseCode(201);
$message->addHeader('Location', 'blablub');

$res = new http\Env\Response;
$res->setBody(new http\Message\Body($message));
$res->send();
```

explicit question is now, is there something like

```
$message->setData(what ever);
```

?

Comment: You need to tell us specifically what is wrong. Code with examples of what you get verses what you expect would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Use [http\Message\Body::append()](https://mdref.m6w6.name/http/Message/Body/append), eg:

```
use http\Env\Response;

$resp = new Response;
$resp->getBody()->append("whatever");
$resp->send();
```